# Problems closing Acitivity after GPS location is retrieved using another Class

Tags: android, multithreading, gps, code-structure

Situation is this:

1. Activity A calls `getLocation()` method from Class B.

Class B handles obtaining GPS locations.

2 Activity A should finish once Class B has finished retrieving GPS
    location.

Activity A calls something like:

```
B.getLocation()
this.finish()
```

i.e. gets the location using method from B and then finishes itself. In reality, A closes before B has a chance to get the location.

How do I structure this correctly so that A waits till B has finished?

Comment: try like location = B.getLocation(); then method return location check if location is not null then call this.finish();

Comment: @Samir That won't work either. For some reason it puts getting the location in the background. And carries on executing further code regardless. i.e. B.getLocation(); then checks if location is null. if it is null thats it, it'll carry on anyway, it won't carry on checking.

Comment: tell me what you want? i think your approach is wrong and create prblm Can you tell me what you want actually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design here is lacking. In fact, you can't just call one `Activity`'s method for the other one, since only one `Activity` can be in foreground at the moment. Your activities should communicate using `Intents`. Here's how it should work:

1. `Activity A` starts `Activity B` using an `Intent`
2. `Activity B` gets location and returns it to `Activity A`, using the `setResult()` method
3. `Activity A` reads the result from `Activity B` in its `onActivityResult()` method
4. `Activity A` finishes

This feels like a better implementation. Actually, if `Activity B` does just get location, you can simple implement it as a `Service` and bind it to `Activity A`. Hope this helps.

Comment: But that does seem like a better implementation/design, thank you.

Comment: @Neeta, Anyway, getting user's location is a long running operation, so if you will call it synchronously, you're running risk of getting an ANR. So you should implement Class B as a separate Thread or a Service and call back to the Activity A when location is acquired.

Comment: @Neeta, Application Not Responsive dialog, known for its Force Close button.

Answer (score 0):

ok you need to do some callback Mechanism, if you are familiar with Basic Java.. Here I am just trying to give you an overview of CallBack in Java...

```
//Here is you class B :

class ClassB {

interface ILocationListerner {


 void setLocations(float lat, float long);


}



ILocationListerner mLocationListener = null;


/// Here is your static method that set Listerner and call by Activity A

public void static setLocationListerner(ILocationListerner listener){

this.mLocationListener = listener;


}


//Gel loaction method.

public static void getLocation(){

////
...
////

mLocationListener.setLocation(lat,lng);





}


}// ClassB ends here


/// Activity A

class ActivityA extends Activity {


 onCreate(){


 ClassB.setLocationListerner(new ILocationListerner {

      @Override
      void setLocations(float lat, float long){

      /// do your stuff and call finish();

      }

} );

ClassB.getLocation();


}

}

}
```

Hope you understand this...